# DevOps Git Connection was reset

Tags: git, azure-devops, visual-studio-2019

I'm working in Visual Studio 2019 v16.9.3. I have a solution with a connection to a DevOps (visualstudio.com) project using Git for the repo.

If I try to run any git commands (fetch, full, push etc.) from either VS or a console window **While I have an Web Broswer Open** then I get the following error:

```
Error encountered while pushing to the remote repository: Git failed with a fatal error.
Git failed with a fatal error.
unable to access 'https://biztalkers.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/SmsRouter/_git/SmsRouter/': 
OpenSSL SSL_connect: Connection was reset in connection to biztalkers.visualstudio.com:443
```

I guess this is due to the web browser user being logged in with a different Microsoft account but I get the same problem when I have a browser tab open with me logged into the target repo.

I am able to work-around by closing all web browsers and re-trying the git command either from VS or a console window.

Any ideas?

Comment: Hi Rob, could you please update your VS2019 to latest V16.9.4? And are your organization connected to AAD already?

Comment: Hi @HughLin-MSFT, I tried updating VS2019 to 16.9.4 but I'm afraid that didn't help. I am working with a personal Microsoft - not an organization account.